# Constant iteration in Arduino code

Tags: arduino

Please, I am curious, what effect do the baud rates of **Software Serial** and **Serial** have on the subsequent execution of my Arduino code? I have noticed a weird behavior in my code. It keeps printing out **Test1**, it never goes further. When I made the baud rates to be the same **(9600)**, I keep getting **ààÀàà** continuously. So I need an an explanation on what is really happening.

test.ino

```
#include "gsm.h"
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(10, 11); // RX, TX
gsm gm;
char temp[10];

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(57600);
  mySerial.begin(9600);
  gm.getMsg(mySerial, 1);
  Serial.print("Test1");
  if(mySerial.available()){
    mySerial.readBytes(temp, 10);
    Serial.print("Test2");
  }
  Serial.print("Test3");
  gm.getText(temp); 
}

void loop() {

}
```

gsm.cpp

```
#include "gsm.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <arduino.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

void gsm::getText(char str[]) {
  char *temp1 = strrchr(str, '\"')+3;
  int l1 = strlen(temp1);
  char *temp2 = strchr(temp1,'\n');
  int l2 = strlen(temp2);   
  int len = l1-l2;
  char msg[10];
  strncpy(msg, temp1, len);
  msg[len] = '\0';
  strncpy(message, msg,len);
}

void gsm::getMsg(SoftwareSerial serial, int index) {
   serial.print("AT+CMGR = ");
   serial.print(index);
   serial.print("\r\n"); 
   delay(300);
}
```

gsm.h

```
#ifndef GSM_H_
#define GSM_H_
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

struct gsm{
  char message[20];
  void getText(char str[]);
  void getMsg(SoftwareSerial serial, int index);
};

#endif
```

Comment: You read a single byte into a char array of length 1 an expect it to be a string?

Comment: its a typo@gre_gor

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the baud rate on the serial monitor to match the baud rate you set with `Serial.begin`.

(Photo credit to [Adafruit](https://www.adafruit.com/))

[image: serial monitor baud rate]